# Automatically start lab VMs with auto-start in Azure

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I would like to enable the solution attached in this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-auto-startup-vm

BUT, as it seems like "just follow the guide and the screen shots" there's something in this guide i can't find.

I'll explain my self:

I would like to schedule 2 DB machines in Azure to start everyday (except Friday and Saturday). I created a test machine to test this. in the testing machine i configured that the machine will power on every day in the morning. I completed this task successfully.

in the link i sent i see that first of all the machine need to be configured with on and off before the "configuration and policies" will be available.

so, how come i can't find what i'm looking for?

You assistance will be highly appreciated

Thanks.

Created a VM.

Configured it with auto-shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that this solution is enable for Dev machines environment and not regular machines